# Magento: Titles for some categories but not for all

Tags: magento

I need to have title  tags on certain categories but not on all. They are displayed by default so what I've done so far is to create a new view.phtml file in app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/catalog/category and comment out the section creating the title, which works fine.
The next stage would be to enable the title on some of the categories. I did this by adding it manually to the category description which is ok but then i got the idea of maybe creating a cms block and using that to do it. To do this there would need to be a markup tag or something to display the current category which I could put in the static block. Is there?.. or is there any other way of doing this?

( I have included the backstory because maybe this is the wrong way to go about turning the title off on category pages altogether.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with

```
<layout>
     <your_target_handler>
           <reference name="head">
                <action method="setTitle"><title>Your title</title></action>
           </reference>
     </your_target_handler>
</layout>
```

or do it via php

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('my title');
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle('my title');
```

Comment: sorry maybe i don't understand or maybe i didn't make it clear in the question but the whole point is to have the title dynamic

Comment: thanks so much - that looks like it will work - i am off this project for a few days but will try later

Answer (score 1):

You could also add an extra attribute to a category which works as a switch for showing or not showing the title (whichever way is the easiest). 
Than adjust the template code so it will check if the title must be displayed or not.

I used the following code to add extra (textarea) attributes to categories in Mage 1.5.0:

```
/* ADD ATTRIBUTES TO MAGENTO BACKEND FOR CATEGORIES 
 * Adding the type
 */
INSERT INTO eav_attribute (entity_type_id, attribute_code, backend_type, frontend_input, frontend_label, default_value, source_model) 
VALUES (9, 'category_from_data', 'text', 'textarea', 'From pricing text', '', '');

/*
 * Source Q:
 * INSERT INTO eav_entity_attribute ( entity_type_id, attribute_set_id, attribute_group_id, attribute_id, sort_order ) VALUES ( 3, 3, 3, <new attribute ID>, <next sort order> );
 * Works but entity_type_id should be 9 for category
 */
INSERT INTO eav_entity_attribute ( entity_type_id, attribute_set_id, attribute_group_id, attribute_id, sort_order ) VALUES ( 9, 12, 7, 9, 25 );

/* 
 * Adding the attribute itself
 */
INSERT INTO `catalog_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `frontend_input_renderer`, `is_global`, `is_visible`, `is_searchable`, `is_filterable`, `is_comparable`, `is_visible_on_front`, `is_html_allowed_on_front`, `is_used_for_price_rules`, `is_filterable_in_search`, `used_in_product_listing`, `used_for_sort_by`, `is_configurable`, `apply_to`, `is_visible_in_advanced_search`, `position`, `is_wysiwyg_enabled`) VALUES
(977, NULL, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, '', 0, 0, 1);
```

You might want to check the db itself and find out what entity_type_id 9 holds in eav_entity_attribute and what the insert id in eav_attribute is after 1st query.

For adding a checkbox attribute I suggest you check the tables and fish for an existing attribute and adjust the parameters in the query accordingly.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: that sounds like it would work, thanks - i am new to magento - i know where to setup product attributes but where do i set category attributes ?

Comment: @buronyasgur I added the SQL which did the job for me. See if it helps you or at least points you in the right direction...